# Foreach row array CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have created a model which joins 2 tables

```
function list_get($id){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db-> select('*')
        ->from('lists')
        ->join('list_items', 'list_items.items_list_id = lists.list_id')
        ->where('items_list_id', $id);
    return $query->get()->row_array();
}
```

In my controller I created the view_list function

```
public function view_list($id = !FALSE){
    $this->load->model('model_lists');
    $data["query"] = $this->model_lists->list_get($id);
    $this->load->model('model_lists');
    if($data["query"]){
        $this->load->view('lists/view_list',$data);
    } else {
        redirect('lists');
    }
}
```

Now my view returns only the first result from the database 
`<?php echo $query['item_url'];?>` How can I create a foreach to show all the results?

Answer (score 1):

change  this line  `return $query->get()->row_array();`
to    `return $query->get()->result_array();`

in view

```
 foreach($query as $querys){

       echo $querys['item_url'];
      echo '</br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `return $query->get()->row_array();` to this

```
return $query->result_array();
```

---

and in view

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this PHP error 

`Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::results_array()`

Comment: it's result_array() , you type results_array(), please remove 's' letter